# Docker: COPY failed: CreateFile, looking for file in strange location

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

Trying to follow the tutorial found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application), but running into problems.

I run the following command from my project dir:

```
docker build -t my.solution .
```

I get the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  111.6kB
Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
 ---> ccfb41c8f5b5
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e29a68e16001
Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 976388139964
Step 4/17 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
 ---> d7ab4e860769
Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ab01220723e
Step 6/17 : COPY my.solution.sln ./
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder564035917\my.solution.sln: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't know why it's trying to find the file in the location it's looking for it.  Can anyone help me?  Is there a config setting I need to make?  My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY my.solution.sln ./
COPY my.solution/my.solution.csproj my.solution/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/my.solution
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my.solution.dll"]
```

**UPDATE**

Per @AlexGera's answer, I tried changing my docker file to:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
VOLUME C:/tmp
COPY my.solution.sln c:/tmp/
COPY my.solution/my.solution.csproj my.solution/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/my.solution
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my.solution.dll"]
```

but the error message doesn't change significantly:

```
docker build -t my.solution .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  111.6kB
Step 1/18 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
 ---> ccfb41c8f5b5
Step 2/18 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e29a68e16001
Step 3/18 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 976388139964
Step 4/18 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
 ---> d7ab4e860769
Step 5/18 : WORKDIR /src
Removing intermediate container 31e30e2346aa
 ---> 61c7df20f3c4
Step 6/18 : VOLUME C:/tmp
 ---> Running in fada6c728151
Removing intermediate container fada6c728151
 ---> 7a650440cc1f
Step 7/18 : COPY my.solution.sln c:/tmp/
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder832533802\my.solution.sln: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: file only be copied to file do some thing like copy my.solution.sln ./my.solution.sln

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Seems to me the standard Dockerfile that comes with a new solution is bugged :/

I moved the Dockerfile up to the solution folder, from PowerShell:

```
mv Dockerfile ../Dockerfile
```

Running the docker build command from there did the trick for me...

Comment: yea its the stupid way Visual Studio creates your project and put the dokcerfile inside the project.. instead of the root where the solution it. Had same issue.. the configu file says go into the project... but as explained the context is already there.. confusing as hell for a newbie but you solution fixed it for me thanks +1

Comment: VS SHOULD is correct to create the dockerfile in the project's folder.
If you have a multi-project solution (usually the case) you would end up with a lot of dockerfiles in the solution folder, which doesn't make sense.
The problem is the generated dockerfile.

Comment: @ShyAgam Don't agree. You just name them differently. Who wants every Dockerfile named "Dockerfile", this is just confusing.

Comment: Yes, that would be confusing. I was referring to a different problem though: Order in the code structure. Putting any file (dockerfile in this case) in a folder that doesn't instinctively tell you "this files belongs to this project/module/component" is usually a good recipe for caos, especially in big projects.

Comment: That Answer lead me to a (in my opinion) better solution.
In the solution directory execute: `docker build -f .\my.solution\Dockerfile -t my.solution .`

Comment: That did the trick for me when using JetBrains Rider - placing the Dockerfile beside the solution file 

Answer (score 5):

The COPY command will copy the file from the build context, or a previous build stage if you specify the stage. With your build command:

```
docker build -t my.solution .
```

The context is `.` which is first sent to the docker engine which places that in a temporary location just for the build.

Therefore with your copy command:

```
Step 6/17 : COPY my.solution.sln ./
```

The file `my.solution.sln` needs to exist in the folder where the build command was run.

For the destination, the file will be copied to the working directory inside the container, or `/src` in your example.

Answer (score 5):

This was probably caused by the .dockerignore file next to you DockerFile, ignoring everything but /obj/*.
Once you copied it to another folder you didn't copy the .dockerignore file, so nothing was excluded and it worked.

Comment: I added a folder to docker ignore and then later was trying to bring in a file in that folder and it caused this issue.  +1 for reminding me...

Comment: This should be the answer, My .dockerignore had a "*" which was ignoring everything under the Dockerfile directory, removed the "*" from dockerignore and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Before copying add a volume in your image to copy where to.
Something like this:

```
VOLUME C:/Users/mysolution
COPY my.solution.sln C:/Users/mysolution
```

Try not to use dots for directory names.

Comment: How does this relate to the WORKDIR?

Comment: window have no /opt

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste. Specify whatever directory you wanna place your solution and suits for your image. ~/mysolution for example

Comment: See my update; did I do as you suggested correctly?  It didn't seem to make a lot of difference.

Comment: I assuming you have located my.solution.sln properly. Are you sure it's in the directory where you run container? Typically it's something related  .
Try just DIR your folder and locate my.solution.sln in place

Answer (score 1):

I found that same situation in a VS2017 Solution where the build is started by docker compose and yml files one directory above the project.

If you want to build by docker build with the docker file directly, you need to move the docker file one level above the context

Answer (score 0):

Use the \\

> `FROM microsoft\\aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build`

see the below example

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.0 .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","DOCKER-API.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I move my Dockerfile to the root folder (where exists .sln and .dockerignore files) and my problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

Perfect suits for who uses visual studio :

run this command :

```
docker build -t . your_application_name/Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile Copy path :

```
["your_application_name/your_application_name.csproj","your_application_name/"]
```

we run the build command docker build command it is unable to find the dockerfile in the project path location.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio creates the Docker file at Project level, however, the Dockerfile is tailored to be run from an upper level (Solution level).

[image]

The easiest way to fix this problem is to go one level up (Solution folder), and specify the project folder:

```
docker build --tag tagone -f Project/Dockerfile .
```